# Deflate Not Working on Windows 64 Apache -- mod_deflate, mod_filter, mod_header are loaded

Tags: php, windows, apache, wamp, deflate

I've seen this question asked on numerous forums, but I haven't found a solution.  I am using WAMP Server, which uses Apache 2.4.4.  If you're no familiar with WAMP, you can easily enable/disable modules through the tray icon, but just to be certain, I have verified this in my httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

I have also used phpinfo() to double-check:

```
Loaded Modules  
core mod_win32 mpm_winnt http_core mod_so mod_access_compat mod_actions mod_alias mod_allowmethods mod_asis mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_filter mod_headers mod_include mod_isapi mod_log_config mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_vhost_alias mod_php5
```

But no matter what I change to my .htaccess or my httpd.conf, my files are not deflated.  I have tried the simple approach (in an .htaccess file confirmed to be working):

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</IfModule>
```

I have tried the complicated approach:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript application/x-httpd-php
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
```

No matter what I try, it simply doesn't do it.  I've verified that the IfModule condition is indeed firing, whether I put it in the proper .htaccess or the httpd.conf.  I've verified that the module is indeed loaded.  I've verified that other modules work correctly (like mod_rewrite).  I am not on shared hosting, so there are no strange configurations or proxies at work here.  I have been tweaking and testing this for days with zero success.  There are similar posts to mine scattered across the Internet, but no answers.  Is there anyone out there who can help solve this problem?  Thank you!

Comment: If you're on **W** AMP server, then you should be loading .dll files, not .so files. .so are Unix libraries.

Comment: Marc B, I think it's just a naming convention.  The other .so modules work just fine.  See this link: http://serverfault.com/questions/111474/why-so-files-also-work-for-windows